# writing scope into model rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am developing application using rails 4.0. I have this code in my Blogs controller

```
@published = params[:published]

@blogs = Blog.published_blogs.where('published >= ? AND published <= ?', (params[:published].to_date).beginning_of_month, (params[:published].to_date).end_of_month)
```

published_blogs is onother scope in my Blog model. I just want to move this query in my Blog model. please help me.

I tried this in my Blog model

```
scope :by_published, lambda{|published| 'published'>=? AND published', (published).to_date.beginning_of_month ,(published).to_date.end_of_month if published.present?}
```

and then changed my controller to

```
@blogs = Blog.published_blogs.by_published(params[:published])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scopes changed again in Rails 4 - which is why I'm uneasy about using them:

```
scope :by_published, ->(published) { where('published >= ? AND published <= ?', (published).to_date.beginning_of_month ,(published).to_date.end_of_month if published.present?)}
```

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :created_before, ->(time) { where("created_at < ?", time) }
end
```

I personally prefer class methods, and they are actually recommended if you are passing parameters:

"However, this is just duplicating the functionality that would be provided to you by a class method."

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.created_before(time)
    where("created_at < ?", time)
  end
end
```

"Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes. These methods will still be accessible on the association objects:"

```
category.articles.created_before(time)
```